# Why do these outlets appear to be "hot"?

Tags: electrical

Using an analog voltmeter, with the fuse removed at the subpanel and no voltage indicated across the 2 wires of the outlet (1928-era ungrounded outlets in the US), several outlets showed exactly 120 volts from EITHER wire to a ground. Is something wrong? They function normally.

Comment: It sounds like your "ground" isn't...what, precisely, are you referencing your measurement to?

Comment: Oh, is it possible there are fuses on both the hot and neutral side? If I only disconnected the neutral side, that would at least explain why one of the wires showed voltage. The "ground" was the female ground socket of an extension cord plugged into a [believed to be] grounded receptacle on a grounded circuit that was added a decade ago, and which goes to the modern main panel.

Comment: Double check that said grounded receptacle is actually grounded, first off...and I'd doubt both hot and neutral are fused, but there are combination failures that could lead to what you describe.

Comment: I don't have access to the book right now, but I actually now think I remember Old Electrical Wiring (by David Shapiro) discussing fuses on both sides sometimes being present in very old circuits. I absolutely might be imagining that though! A plug-in tester thinks that the newer outlet is grounded, for what it's worth.

Comment: Double-sided fusing is far older than your house -- it was done in extremely early circuits but nowhere else that I know of.

Comment: Ah, good to know. Sounds like some troubleshooting is in order. Thanks for the thoughts!

Comment: @PhilEsra if you only disconnected the neutral, it would explain why **both** wires show 120V.  Any load anywhere in the circuit, even the minisule vampire load of a GFCI, would "pull up" the neutral to 120V.  That is normal and will happen in any circuit where neutral is interrupted.  It's not unsafe in a system built to code, because neutral and ground are isolated from each other everywhere except the main panel.  (And that's why.)

Comment: @Harper, thanks, that's great info. I do appear to have fuses on both sides--removing either of 2 side-by-side fuses cuts the power to the relevant fixture/outlet. The fact that a GFCI is a load, and that its load closes the break in the circuit at the outlet, had not occurred to me--everything makes MUCH more sense now. THANKS! If you add that info as an "answer" I will "accept" it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only disconnected the neutral, it would explain why both wires show 120V. Any load anywhere in the circuit, even the miniscule vampire load of a GFCI, would "pull up" the neutral to 120V. That is normal and will happen in any circuit where neutral is interrupted.

Is that safe?  Yes - in a system built to modern code.  Neutral and ground are isolated from each other everywhere except the main panel. (And that's why.) Neutral from circuit 1 isn't cross-connected to circuit 2 (which could overload circuit 2's neutral if it were).

Of course old work can have a variety of defects. In modern work, there's one place in particular where neutral floating to 120V would be a problem, and that's in NEMA 10 outlets for stoves or dryers, because they treat neutral as ground and put neutral on the metal frame of the appliance.

Comment: As an FYI for others, according to _Old Electrical Wiring_ (2nd edition), by David Shapiro, fuse boxes "installed before adoption of the 1923 NEC" may "fuse both energized and neutral conductors."

Comment: Elsewhere in the book he says "Section 807 of the 1925 NEC authorized inspectors to require" that both energized and neutral be fused.